# error sqlite3 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I've used sqlite before. My friend sent me a skeleton rails app that I am trying to run.

When I try to do "rails server" or "thin start" it says

> Could not find sqlite3-0.1.1 in any of the sources"

I tried to do bundle install but it throws this error:

> Installing sqlite3 (0.1.1) /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:364:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': sqlite3 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1. (Gem::InstallError)
>   from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:135:in`install'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in`run'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in`each'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in`install'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in`send'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in`invoke_task'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in`start'
>   from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/bin/bundle:13
>   from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
>   from /usr/bin/bundle:19

I don't know why it's trying to look in the 1.8 folder with Ruby 1.9.2 installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have ruby 1.9.2 installed, but is it the first one on your path? what does `which ruby` point to?

Comment: /usr/bin/ruby
that's the output of "which ruby"

Comment: and what does `ruby -v` tell you?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

wtf...it was just 1.9.2 last night...I have it installed...i saw it last night...what would have made it revert back?

Comment: That should answer your question. Just because you have ruby 1.9.2 installed doesn't mean you're using it. You probably didn't update your path (or your installer didn't).

Comment: last time i did ruby -v it said 1.9.2...but oh well...so how do i make sure i'm using 1.9.2?

Comment: Personally, I now use rvm to deal with this, but you can update your paths; I'm not sure what the Mac OS X specific solution to do this is; I could only answer for Windows or Linux, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am using rvm as well...but I am a noob and don't know how to set the path to 1.9.2...how do you do it?

Comment: if you're using rvm, simply type `rvm use 1.9.2` in the terminal. Then you'll have to run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bundle` command is pointing to your system Ruby, type the following to see which Ruby your Bundler is pointed to: `head -1 $(which bundle)`  Either that needs to be pointed at the Ruby you want to use and/or you need to use the Ruby you want to use to install the Bundler gem (which will put the right shebang line in your `bundle` executable).